# Debugging jPlayer Flash mp3 playback

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome, jplayer

Since [this Chrome issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=386073) resulted in jPlayer 1.6.0 using the Flash solution for mp3 playback in Chrome 36, I've discovered my mp3s won't play via the Flash plugin. The mp3s play fine via the HTML5 solution in Firefox 30 and IE 11.

Note I'm not interested in fixing playback to use HTML 5 instead of Chrome - the newest version of jPlayer does that. Instead, I want to understand why playback via Flash is not working.

The mp3s are hosted on archive.org.

What I observe when I start playing is that in the Chrome Network inspector, I get one request for the mp3 URL with Status Finished, and then another request for the same URL that sits in Status (pending) forever.

What I see in Firefox from the HTML5 solution is two requests to the mp3 URL that both receive 302 redirects, and then a long running request to the actual mp3 URL which successfully streams the mp3 for playback

jPlayer inspector shows the progress and timeupdate metrics twitching between 3 and 4, and loadstart, play and waiting having all occurred but sit at 0.

So I think the Flash player isn't handling the redirect probably. But I'm unsure of how to go about troubleshooting this issue.

I've created a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e4WnF/4/ to demonstrate the issue.

I've attempted to use Wireshark to work out what is going on. Whilst with Firefox using the HTML 5 player I see the GET request that results in a 302, I see no sign of this GET request under Chrome.

I've worked around the issue by moving to jPlayer 1.6.4, but this doesn't change the fact that my mp3s will not work in browsers without HTML 5 audio support.

```
Thanks
```

Comment: Can you post a full example on JSFiddle and/or this question?  Your page will be fixed some day, and this question won't be available to help others.  Also, Flash typically follows redirects... I've found that it's easiest to debug these problems with a tool like Fiddler.  Chrome's developer tools report things a bit differently when it comes to how media is accessed.  With Fiddler, you can see what would be requested by a proxy.  With Wireshark you can be absolutely sure of what went over the wire.

Comment: JSFiddle and Wireshark results added to question

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem affecting loads of people, and it's caused by a recent Chrome change, which has now been rolled back, however until that filters through to the updates, you'll need to make some changes. Over at the [jPlayer group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jplayer/bpzsIlPBTAU/7j3MXDrTFwcJ) there are at least ten threads and a [jplayer bug ticket](https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/issues/223#issuecomment-46550769) about this issue. There's also a [Chrome bug tracker ticket](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=386073) about this.

It turns out that jPlayer and other sites like Soundcloud weren't actually sticking to the RFC 3003 spec, and when Chrome tightened up their code, this broke it. Chrome have now rolled back this change, but until that filters through, you can either download the latest jplayer code from github, or make the following immediate change to the jquery.jplayer.js file around line 696 so that it looks like this:

```
mp3: {
    //codec: 'audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"',
    codec: 'audio/mpeg',
    flashCanPlay: true,
    media: 'audio'
},
```

Please let me know if this fixes things.

Comment: I've already updated to the latest version from github. My problem though is that this means Flash playback doesn't work on my site. I want to debug the issue with Flash, not the issue with Flash being used instead of HTML 5.

Comment: OK, I'm glad I was able to help promptly with the original issue - please don't forget to upvote and "mark as answer" as I resolved that part. 
Moving on to the completely different issue of why Flash won't work for you, can you now provide a complete page using jplayer 2.6.4.
I'm not having any issues - I've cloned your fiddle to be solution: "flash,html", and also set IE dev tools to be IE7, and it both cases the inspector shows "jPlayer's flash solution is being used and will support: mp3" and it plays fine for me - Chrome, IE and Firefox, all in "flash" mode.

Comment: Sorry, the post is called "Debugging jPlayer Flash mp3 playback", and since the beginning contained the statement "So I think the Flash player isn't handling the redirect probably. But I'm unsure of how to go about troubleshooting this issue." It's pretty clear that I'm looking for advice debugging Flash even without my clarifications to the question so I'm not going to upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: In terms of the actual problem, now I'm quite confused. My fiddle works for me at work, but does not at home. I'm guessing I must have different Chrome versions in both locations.

Comment: But what I'm really looking for is someone who can talk me through how to debug the Flash behavior of jPlayer. Is there a debug log I can take advantage of? Some other way I can listen to events from the Flash player? Or another way I can get visibility into its failure.